# Distributions of variance and mean

Tags: self-study, variance, mean, t-distribution, f-distribution

I am adding this again with details as suggested

The following questions were asked. State if true

1. The test statistic for the difference of population variance follows an F-distribution
2. The test statistic for the difference of population means, when population variance are unknown, follow a T-distribution

I went through my study guide and know that the first one is   simply a ratio of $\chi^2$ variance and the second an estimate of mean. So the I chose false, but I am told both are true. How is this the case?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F-test_of_equality_of_variances

Comment: (1) is the ratio of variance